# RadBusyIndicator always selected when designer is clicked

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml, telerik

I have a RadBusyIndicator on my UserControl like so:

```
<Grid>
    <!-- Other Content -->
    <t:RadBusyIndicator IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy}"></t:RadBusyIndicator>
</Grid>
```

And whenever I click in the design view it goes to the BusyIndicator.

I can set the Panel.ZIndex to be negative to select the "Other Content", but this will cause the RadBusyIndicator to be behind the "Other Content"

I tried using a binding for the ZIndex like so:

```
<t:RadBusyIndicator Panel.ZIndex="{Binding BusyZIndex}" IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy}"></t:RadBusyIndicator>
```

But it doesn't help.

So the question is:

**How do I have the RadBusyIndicator on "Top" of all the "Other Content" but still be able to click(in the designer) and go to the xaml line for that control?**

Comment: A better way to do this is to use `d:IsHidden="true"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BusyIndicator needs to be "on top" to be in front of the controls. That makes it also on top in the designer.

There may be better ways of solving this, but what comes into mind is to make the BusyPanel a Resource on the UserControl, and then add it in the Grid control OnApplyTemplate or Loaded by code.

**Here is the UserControl's XAML.**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication2.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:t="REFERENCE.TO.THE.RAD.ASSEMBLY" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <t:RadBusyIndicator x:Key="TheBusyIndicator" IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy}">
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Button Content="Some content to the button"
                Height="25"
                Width="200"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I have added the BusyIndicator as a Resource with the Key "TheBusyIndicator".
I have also added x:Name="LayoutRoot" to the Grid which will contain the BusyIndicator.
The Grid can of course have another name if it in fact is not the layout root control.

By adding the BusyIndicator to the Children collection last, it will appear in front of all other controls that are added by the markup code.

**Here is the code**

UserControl's Constructor:

```
public UserControl1()
{
    this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(UserControl1_Loaded);
}
```

The execting code:

```
private void UserControl1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.LayoutRoot.Children.Add(this.Resources["TheBusyIndicator"] as RadBusyIndicator);
}
```

I never use UserControls anymore, only CustomControls where the XAML goes to "Generic.xaml" and I have no editor to work in. So I have not seen this problem for a while.

Comment: Works like a champ!
Thanks :)